# Compare multiple columns in r

Tags: r

How can I compare multiple columns (A, B, C) of a tibble and create a new column (D) that contains the same value iff all columns are equal (NAs should be ignored) and a special value (e.g., "ERROR") otherwise.

```
data <- tibble(A = as.factor(LETTERS[c(NA,2:9)]),
               B = as.factor(LETTERS[c(1:5,NA,7:9)]),
               C = as.factor(LETTERS[c(1:6,26,8:9)]))
```

Giving:

```
> data
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  A     B     C    
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 NA    A     A    
2 B     B     B    
3 C     C     C    
4 D     D     D    
5 E     E     E    
6 F     NA    F    
7 G     G     Z    
8 H     H     H    
9 I     I     I
```

Add code here:

```
data |>
 mutate(D = 'magic')
```

Desired result:

```
> tibble(A = as.factor(LETTERS[c(NA,2:9)]),
+        B = as.factor(LETTERS[c(1:5,NA,7:9)]),
+        C = as.factor(LETTERS[c(1:6,26,8:9)]),
+        D = as.factor(c(LETTERS[1:6],'ERROR',LETTERS[8:9])))
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  A     B     C     D    
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 NA    A     A     A    
2 B     B     B     B    
3 C     C     C     C    
4 D     D     D     D    
5 E     E     E     E    
6 F     NA    F     F    
7 G     G     Z     ERROR
8 H     H     H     H    
9 I     I     I     I
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
func <- function(...) {
  z <- na.omit(unlist(list(...)))
  if (length(unique(z)) == 1) as.character(z)[1] else "ERROR"
}
data %>%
  mutate(D = mapply(func, A, B, C))
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   A     B     C     D    
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>
# 1 NA    A     A     A    
# 2 B     B     B     B    
# 3 C     C     C     C    
# 4 D     D     D     D    
# 5 E     E     E     E    
# 6 F     NA    F     F    
# 7 G     G     Z     ERROR
# 8 H     H     H     H    
# 9 I     I     I     I
```

While I generally don't recommend using `apply` to a whole frame (it tends to make a whole copy in memory when converting it to a `matrix`, which can be expensive and often unnecessary), I think it'll work well enough here. For that, I'll borrow the suggestion from @jpsmith's answer:

```r
apply(data, 1, func)
# [1] "A"     "B"     "C"     "D"     "E"     "F"     "ERROR" "H"     "I"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a base R alternative (thanks @r2evans for improved code):

```
data$D <- apply(data, 1, \(x) if(all(x == na.omit(x)[1], na.rm = TRUE)) unique(unlist(x)[!is.na(x)], na.rm = TRUE)
                                 else "Error")
```

Output:

```
  A     B     C     D    
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <chr>
1 NA    A     A     A    
2 B     B     B     B    
3 C     C     C     C    
4 D     D     D     D    
5 E     E     E     E    
6 F     NA    F     F    
7 G     G     Z     Error
8 H     H     H     H    
9 I     I     I     I
```

Comment: Thanks @r2evans and user1 for pointing that out - I have made the edit to reflect this improved code and checked that it works when [B,1] is changed to Y